# Regex duplicates C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have:

```
<div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="http://www.printesaurbana.ro/2010/05/unghiile-la-control-predare-caseta.html#comment-6069">
            14.05.2010 la 2:42 pm</a>       </div>
```

I want select 14.05.2010 la 2:42 pm

I try:

```
Regex Datet = new Regex(@""">\s*(.+?)</a>\s*</div>");
```

Problem is that I recive in my results additional catch.

Comment: What additional catch? Did you consider using an HTML parser for this task?

Comment: How about `<a[^>]+>\s*([^>]+)</a>` ?

Answer (score 2):

An HTML parser would be much better for this task. See this famous stackoverflow answer regarding using regex with html [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)